# Request for code review and improvement suggestion ( was: Question on making a function Listable )

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Clean-up of question per request of acl:

I have the following code

```
AddGeometry[scg_, tfg_, geo_] := 

Module[{
i,
georec},

If[StringQ[geo[[2,1]]]&&StringMatchQ[geo[[2,1]],"GE"],   (* DIRTY, BWAH *)
    AddAsChild[scg, tfg, geo],
    (
    i=1;
    While[i<=Length[geo],
        georec=geo[[i]];
        AddGeometry[scg, tfg, georec];
        i++
    ]
    )
]
```

]

```
SetAttributes[AddGeometry, HoldAll];
```

geo_ looks like this:

```
{
{4, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 0, 0}, 4}}}, 5, 2}, 
{7, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 3, 0}, 1}}}, 5, 2},
{12, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 5, 0}, 2}}}, 5, 2},
}
```

It contains 1, 2, ... n records of type
    {4, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 0, 0}, 4}}}, 5, 2}

The calling code looks like

```
c1 = NewCube[]
```

( c1 gets value like {4, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 0, 0}, 4}}}, 5, 2} ) etc.

```
AddGeometry[scg, tfg, c1]
```

OR when multiple geometries need to be added:

```
AddGeometry[scg, tfg, {c1, c2, c3}]
```

The code above works.

### Question:

- Is there a cleaner way ( using polymorphism ) to implement this?

From @acl:

```
AddGeometry[scg_, tfg_, geo_] := 
Module[{
    georec=geo}, 

    AddAsChild[scg, tfg, georec]

] /; MatchQ[geo, {_, {"GE", __}, __}];      

AddGeometry[scg_, tfg_, geo_] := 
Module[{},
    Map[AddGeometry[scg, tfg, #] & ,geo]
]
```

Comment: I am not understanding the question.  Using `SetAttributes[AddGeometry, {HoldAll, Listable}];` and `AddGeometry[scg, tfg, {c1, c2}]` yields `{AddAsChild[scg, tfg, NewCube[{0, 0, 0}, 4]], 
 AddAsChild[scg, tfg, NewCube[{10, 0, 0}, 4]]}` which seems correct.  Also, how does `NewGeometry` relate to anything?  Pardon me if I am just being stupid.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I (perhaps incorrectly) interpreted the question as "directly setting Listable attribute is not satisfactory" for unspecified reasons. It seems the rest of the implementation (not given here) is also important (see for example my attempted answer which does not work in the actual environment ndroock1 has set up)

Comment: if you don't like the {_,{"GE,__},__} mess (I don't), consider creating a "structure" with head geoRec which will hold the records, and you could then use AddGeometry[scg_, tfg_, geo_geoRec] (or the relevant /; MatchQ structure), which is less ugly. start a new question if you want for this.

Comment: for instance, you could represent {4, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 0, 0}, 4}}}, 5, 2} as georec[4, "GE", "CU", {0, 0, 0}, 4, 5, 2], and then if (say) {0,0,0} is some sort of point, define getPoint[el_georec]:=georec[[4]] and so on. this will protect your programs from breaking every time you change your data structures (of course this is standard in other languages, but it may not be so obvious in mathematica that you can do it this way)

Comment: @acl, what do you have against `grpat = {_, {"GE", __}, __}`, function, performance, aesthetics, other?  I thought of your suggestion as well, but I didn't want to require that the OP change his data format.

Comment: @Mr., robustness mainly. If I were writing this myself I'd do it the way I described and write constrictors, getters and setters so that I could modify the structures to my hearts content without worrying about breaking anything outside it (ie I'd build an interface). But we all do things in different ways (and I guess Leonid will now suddenly appear and do some magic that'll leave the rest of us weak-kneed)

Comment: @acl, those are valid points.  I guess I am hesitant to tell someone to change their code/methods outside of the immediate question unless they have to.  I am not sure why.  Again I could learn from Leonid, as he manages to show superior methods without telling the OP "you're doing it wrong."

Comment: @Mr. Sure, I am not telling ndroock1 to do it "my" way. I just guessed what he found ugly and suggested a possible way to hide the ugliness (at the price of performance probably)

Comment: @acl - Yesterday's exercise was helpful. Goodbye code, back to the drawing board. I seriously appreciate the help of this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to the updated question, how about

```
 ClearAll[AddGeometry];
 SetAttributes[AddGeometry, HoldAll];

 AddGeometry[scg_, tfg_, geo_] := Module[{}, AddAsChild[scg, tfg, geo]] /; MatchQ[geo, {_, {"GE", __}, __}];

 AddGeometry[scg_, tfg_, geo_] := (AddGeometry[scg, tfg, #] & /@ geo)
```

which I tested by

```
 c1 = {4, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 0, 0}, 4}}}, 5, 2};
 g = {{4, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 0, 0}, 4}}}, 5, 
2}, {7, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 3, 0}, 1}}}, 5, 
2}, {12, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 5, 0}, 2}}}, 5, 2}};

AddGeometry[scg, tfg, c1]
AddGeometry[scg, tfg, g]
```

which gave

```
AddAsChild[scg, tfg, {4, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 0, 0}, 4}}}, 5, 2}]
```

and

```
 {AddAsChild[scg, tfg, {4, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 0, 0}, 4}}}, 5, 2}], 
 AddAsChild[scg, tfg, {7, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 3, 0}, 1}}}, 5, 2}], 
  AddAsChild[scg, tfg, {12, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 5, 0}, 2}}}, 5, 2}]}
```

Also, if `AddAsChild` works purely with sideffects, one can use `Scan` instead of `Map` to avoid getting a returned list of `Null`s (or modify the second definition to `AddGeometry[scg_, tfg_, geo_] := (AddGeometry[scg, tfg, #]; & /@ geo)` instead).

Comment: Can you please explain the second statement?

Comment: @ndroock1 I guess you mean the first statement [I flipped the order since it was wrong :)] geo_List matches objects with head List, and the definition then simply maps your AddGeometry (which is now the second statement) over the list. If the third argument is not a list, the first definition doesn't match and the second is tried. Do you really need HoldAll, by the way? I think it would be easier without it

Comment: @ndroock1 by the way AddGeometry[scg, tfg, #] & /@ geo is the same as Map[AddGeometry[scg, tfg, #] &, geo]

Comment: Because it doesn't work. Note that AddGeometry is a function in a package. Have you included the SetAttributes bit?

Comment: First of all the difference is that I have defined the AddGeometry's in a Package. Are you sure this can be put in a Package?
AddGeometry[scg_, tfg_, geo_List] := AddGeometry[scg, tfg, #] & /@ geo
Because I get a lot of error msgs.
Must go out now. #$*^&$* Will work on this later. Thanks for help sofar.

Comment: @ndroock1 In principle putting it in a package shouldn't be a problem (ie, if it worked in your version, it should have worked in the version I give). But who knows? Maybe you can give some more details.

Comment: @ndroock1 see new attempt in my answer... if this does not work, could you explain what is not happening there that should have been? to me it seems that the output I get is the desired one; if not, could you explain why?

Comment: So you suggest I add this to the current code
/; MatchQ[geo, {_, {"GE", __}, __}];
And then add this line
 AddGeometry[scg_, tfg_, geo_] := (AddGeometry[scg, tfg, #] & /@ geo)

In the private section. No changes in public part.
I'll try this now.

Comment: I made a typo. It still doesn't work, but no more strange mma errors. Maybe I can get this too work. Will report back.

Comment: @ndroock1: maybe it's useful if you also clarify how it fails. as far as I can tell, the behaviour I show in my answer is correct, is it not? is it not correct and you expect something else?

Comment: @acl. Have you used functions in a Package? Because that may explain differences.

Comment: @acl. A lot of miscommunication because of the use of a Package but your solution works ( after slight modification ) and have edited in the question.

I am not entirely sure if this is the improvement I was looking for. What do you think? Comparing the two?

Comment: @ndroock1 I guess it's conceptually cleaner this way but I get the feeling your structures could be modified to make things less dependent on magical structures (eg this will all break if you change the way you define the georecs, eg to extend your program). but without seeing the rest of the code, who knows (and in any case, this discussion is getting too complicated to be carried out as comments!). anyway, good that it finally works!

Comment: @acl - Yep. Looking at it a bit longer, you def. improved the code. The match string can be made shorter. I am maintaining a graph with various node 'types' in one list, cleaning that up is for later.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I posted a useless "solution" earlier without thinking.  You may try:

```
ClearAll[AddGeometry]

SetAttributes[AddGeometry, HoldAll];

grpat = {_, {"GE", __}, __};

AddGeometry[scg_, tfg_, geo_] /; Head[geo] === List := 
 AddAsChild[scg, tfg, #] & /@ 
  Quiet[geo /. (x : grpat) | {x : grpat ..} :> {x}]
```

Which allows:

```
records =
  {{4, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 0, 0}, 4}}}, 5, 2},
   {3, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 1, 2}, 4}}}, 7, 1}};

AddGeometry[scg, tfg, records]

(* Out =
{AddAsChild[scg, tfg, {4, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 0, 0}, 4}}}, 5, 2}], 
 AddAsChild[scg, tfg, {3, {"GE", {"CU", {{0, 1, 2}, 4}}}, 7, 1}]}
*)
```

If you do not desire output from `AddGeometry` you can use `Scan` rather than `Map`.

Comment: My own answer works but is too dirty to my taste. All I want is if geo contains a 'query' of 'records', i.e. multiple records then unpack and process them one by one. Preferably in Mathematica style so that the list is recognized, etc., etc.

So
    AddGeometry[scg_, tfg_, geo_] /; Head[geo] === List := 
does not work in the given answer.

Comment: My error / misunderstanding may be to do with SetAttributes HoldAll, I am not sure. The variable scg is ( read: will eventually be ) a collection of records read in from an external file. Scg will be read by a user in a Notebook. Maintenance of scg is done by functions in a package. The same is true for tfg which is a subset of the file. Geo will contain new data created by the user in a Notebook session.

Comment: @ndroock1 perhaps you can clean up your question and give examples of desired output for a given input? at the moment it's all a bit confusing.